# Share some part of a static library

Tags: iphone, static

I'm pretty new to static libraries. I recently created one library because I have a lot of source code, and the updates of my projects ended as a nightmare.
So, this is a static library for iPhone.
My question is quite simple : I use this library for me and my company. But, how can I use a portion of it to make projects for my clients ? For example, I have a class which reads PDF or Photos, depending of the initialization parameters.
I don't want my client able to use the photo part, just by seeing the headers. How can i achieve that ? I thought to remove some parts of the headers i will give to my client, but i'm pretty sure there are better options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you are using objective C code, it will not be enough to just remove the headers since a smart client will be able to "ask" the code about its interface by using `class-dump`.

So if you want to be certain that the code is not available to your clients, you need to remove it completely from your static library.

Update:
[CocoaReverseEngineering](http://culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering) provides information about how to access the hidden information in frameworks and libraries. But you can also use it so you know what's possible and thus preventing it happening.